# Angularjs doesn't trigger event handled by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to trigger event on a `<A>` element with `mousedown` event handled by `addEventListener` call but I don't know why it doesn't work.
I tried to use `angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');` but it only triggers event handler specified via `ng-click`.

In the code below when I click on 'trigger' link only 'first' is printed to console. How do I make it print 'zero' as well?

[JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/vuxolo/4/edit?html,js,console,output)

**HTML:**

```html
<a id='zero' href="#">zero</a><br/>
<a id="first" href="" ng-click="firstLinkClick()">first</a>
</br>
<a id="trigger" href="" ng-click="triggerLinkClick()">trigger</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
document.getElementById('zero').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('zero');
}, false);

app.controller('myCtrl', function myCtrl($timeout, $scope) {
  $scope.firstLinkClick = function() {
    console.log('first');
  };

  $scope.triggerLinkClick = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      var el = document.getElementById('zero');
      angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');
    }, 100);

    $timeout(function() {
      var el = document.getElementById('first');
      angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');
    }, 100);
  };
});
```

Comment: bind the click event to `#zero` with angularjs as well. just like you did with the other two. why you need to do it outside of angular?

Comment: @Amir: #zero is an element generated by 3rd library so I can't change it. I want to simulate user behavior to click on it.

Comment: @georgeawg: Thank you for the information, but I'm not sure how it will solve my problem? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular uses jqLite internally. If you load jQuery before Angular it will use jQuery instead of jqLite.

`triggerHandler` only triggers events that are added by jqLite/jQuery.

To trigger events added by `addEventListener` you need to use the standard API.

For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('zero');
el.click();
```

Or:

```
var el = document.getElementById('zero');
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

If you need to support older browsers you can start by reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript).